# Error in publishing solution to a folder - Self hosted .NET

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, publish, webassembly

I have an app/solution with multiple projects inside (.NET 6 - self-hosted Blazor WASM)
It can build and run in debugging without any issues.

Now, i tried to publish it for testing in some of our local servers, and i try to publish it to a folder, and run as an .exe.

Problem is, when i try to publish it, somewhere after building succesfully, i receive the following error :

```
Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.6_0.targets(412,5): Error : System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ComputeBlazorPublishAssets.GroupExistingStaticWebAssets(Dictionary`2 assemblyAssets, Dictionary`2 nativeAssets, Dictionary`2 satelliteAssemblyAssets, Dictionary`2 symbolAssets, Dictionary`2 compressedRepresentations)
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ComputeBlazorPublishAssets.Execute()
```

Any ideas what could cause this ?
I am using VS 2022 (Enterprise).

Answer (score 2):

This error seems a lot like an open issue [#37610](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37610) - Blazor AOT compilation fails at ComputeBlazorPublishAssets.GroupExistingStaticWebAssets

Here are [the steps](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37610#issuecomment-945650189) to further diagnose the problem:

> You can capture a binary log with `dotnet publish /bl` and use MSBuild structured log viewer to look at the ComputeBlazorPublishAssets task. Within there, if you expand the parameters, it'll show all the ExistingAssets and you can get a better idea of what's happening. (You'll see the duplicated asset)

You can download MSBuild structured log viewer from here: https://msbuildlog.com/

Comment: I found the .gzip files that are duplicate (4 pcs).
Problem is: they reference different .dll, I have the exact same issue the guy in the #37610 issue is describing.
Problem is: how the hell can I fix this, as there seems to be no fix currently...

Comment: @AlexIvan Seems like the potential fix [was merged](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/commit/4fe56ed95295b4206879beec572f0fd66432e745) to `main` of `dotnet/sdk` on Nov 8. But they don't seem to have a release with these changes yet. It looks like the issue is tricky to reproduce. Could you please add some reproduce steps to the question?